# Flutter looking for date picker

Tags: flutter

I am too new in flutter I need to know is there any widget or package for date picker something like this?

[image]

I am looking for something similar to this I try to find in flutter builtin packages but not able to find similar

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is UI oriented, however, the specific widget you have posted does not come **built-in**, in-fact most widgets come in a *skeleton* form, and design is left to you, therefore, your imagination is the only limit to UI designs.

Despite this, the ever-growing flutter community has developed multiple packages for all sorts of widget designs. You may find a package close to what you have shown, [here](https://fluttergems.dev/date-time-picker/#:%7E:text=The%20Syncfusion%20Flutter%20Date%20Range,navigation%20to%20the%20desired%20date.).